# Minimum and maximum values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the output of my function (key, value):

```
foo , 1
foo , 3
foo , 6
foo , 0
foo , 1
bar , 1
bar , 2
bar , 3
bar , 4
bar , 5
```

Key is string, value is integer. How can I get only min and max values for each key at the output of my function:

```
foo , 0
foo , 6
bar , 1
bar , 5
```

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: What is the exact type of your output? a `DataFrame` or large `str`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
alist = [{"foo": 1},
         {"foo": 3},
         {"foo": 6},
         {"foo": 0},
         {"foo": 1},
         {"bar": 1},
         {"bar": 2},
         {"bar": 3},
         {"bar": 4},
         {"bar": 5}]


def getMinMax(alist):
    dict_min = {}
    dict_max = {}
    for item in alist:
        for key in item:
            if key in dict_min.keys():
                if dict_min[key] > item[key]:
                    dict_min[key] = item[key]
            else:
                dict_min[key] = item[key]

            if key in dict_max.keys():
                if dict_max[key] < item[key]:
                    dict_max[key] = item[key]
            else:
                dict_max[key] = item[key]
    return dict_min, dict_max
if __name__ == '__main__':
    dict_min, dict_max = getMinMax(alist)
    print(dict_min, dict_max)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Without `Pandas`:

Assuming you data input is a large `str`ing, try using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) and [`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html?highlight=itemgetter#operator.itemgetter) with [`list.extend`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter as ig
s = '''foo , 1
foo , 3
foo , 6
foo , 0
foo , 1
bar , 1
bar , 2
bar , 3
bar , 4
bar , 5'''
lst = [[i.split(' , ')[0], int(i.split(' , ')[1])] for i in s.splitlines()]
newlist = []
for x, y in groupby(lst, ig(0)):
    g = list(y)
    newlist.extend([(x, max(g, key=ig(1))[1]), (x, min(g, key=ig(1))[1])])
print(newlist)
```

Output:

```
[('foo', 6), ('foo', 0), ('bar', 5), ('bar', 1)]
```

---

## With `Pandas` <sub>(recommended)</sub>:

If your data is a `pandas` dataframe, like below:

```
col1  col2
0  foo     1
1  foo     3
2  foo     6
3  foo     0
4  foo     1
5  bar     1
6  bar     2
7  bar     3
8  bar     4
9  bar     5
```

You could try:

```
print(df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: f'{x.min()[1]},{x.max()[1]}').str.split(',', expand=True))
```

Output:

```
      0  1
col1      
bar   1  5
foo   0  6
```

If you want to change the column names, try:

```
df = df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda x: f'{x.min()[1]},{x.max()[1]}').str.split(',', expand=True)
df.columns = ['min', 'max']
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     min max
col1        
bar    1   5
foo    0   6
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
bar=[]
foo=[]

for string in output:
    if string[0:2] == bar:
       bar.append(string[-1])
    elif string[0:2] == foo:
       foo.append(string[-1])

for i in bar: 
    int(maxbar) = int(i)
    if int(i)> int(maxbar):
        maxbar = i

for j in foo:
    int(maxfoo) = int(j)
    if int(j)>int(maxfoo):
        int(maxfoo)=int(j)

print("max bar=", maxbar, "maxfoo=",maxfoo)
```